# Default types of signed, unsigned, const and volatile

Tags: c, sizeof

On running the following code:

```
int main()
{
    int a = sizeof(signed) + sizeof(unsigned);
    int b = sizeof(const) + sizeof(volatile);

    printf("%d",a+++b);

    return 0;
}
```

in visual c++, I get an output as 16. Is the default data type of `signed`, `unsigned`, `const` and `volatile` considered `int`?

Comment: Were you really in such a hurry to write this question?

Comment: What's the reason behind the obscure additions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not just these qualifiers, the default type of C language is **int**. So if you dont specify data type at someplace, the compiler will assume **int**.

For example if you don't declare a function and use it, the compiler will give you a warning and assume that the function returns int.

Answer (score 4):

First: `sizeof` is not a function, it's an operator. If it were a function, how would you implement it? You can't, which is the point.

And yes, the default type for those qualifiers is `int`.

Answer (score 1):

your program isn't standard C:

```
int a = sizeof(signed) + sizeof(unsigned);
```

is, ok, `signed` and `int` are in fact synonyms as a are `unsigned` and `unsigned int`.

```
int b = sizeof(const) + sizeof(volatile);
```

these are not allowed in C. Historically there might have been a time that these where interpreted as `int`, too, but you shouldn't rely on that, and your compiler should weep.

```
printf("%d",a+++b);
```

I even refuse to look at how this should be parsed and what the result should be, since this has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: I agree with the sentiment, but I'm pretty sure you actually know quite well how it is parsed and what the result should be.